# Recursion finding path

Tags: java, recursion

I'm trying to find a path between two points on a map.

When it breaks out from the loop and returns the weight, it goes to the else statement and calls find again. Why does the code do this?

```
public int find() throws LinkException {
    Node currentNode = map.getNode(origin);
    int weight = 0;
    return find(currentNode, null, weight);
}

private int find(Node currentNode, Node pastNode, int weight) throws LinkException {
    for (Node futureNode : currentNode.getLinks()) {
        if (currentNode == futureNode || futureNode == pastNode) {
            continue;
        }
        weight += currentNode.getLink(futureNode).getWeight();
        pastNode = currentNode;
        currentNode = futureNode;
        if (currentNode.getName().equals(destination)) { // Here we reach the destination
            break;
        } else {
            find(currentNode, pastNode, weight);
        }
     }
     return weight;
}
```

Comment: Use the debugger to follow the flow of your program.

Comment: just debug it to see what happens exactly... also, insteadof breaking you could just return `weight`

Comment: I observed this behaviour while debugging. When return statement is reached it goes back to the else branch and calls itself again.

Comment: Quite apart from understanding why this is happening, you should probably change the way your program works: as it is, it is likely that it will loop infinitely on three nodes in a triangle without finding the solution. You should check known algorithms:  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra's_algorithm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's how recursion works. You have multiple nested calls to `find()` happening at the same time. When the innermost call finishes, the next-innermost resumes its operation and proceeds to the next operation of its `for` loop.

By the way, you are ignoring the return value of the recursive call to `find()`. That doesn't look right.

Comment: So I need a flag it exit from all calls?

Comment: @locke: That depends on the logic you're trying to implement.